# How can I delete a WhatsApp chat with a specific contact from my app

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I am not able to find the URI for it.

Answer (score 2):

To delete a specific conversation, open WhatsApp, find the conversation, long press on it, and you'll see a delete icon on the top right. Press on it, and it will ask you if you also want to delete media that was sent in the conversation. Choose accordingly, and press *delete*

[image]